# UIDevice.currentDevice().model not returning as a simulator anymore

Tags: uiimage, ios-simulator, swift2, xcode7

I have an image that I'm generating in an app, and trying to save in the simulator to examine after generation.
In previous versions of my app, to save an image to my computer while running on the simulator, I would use the following code:

```
    let img = self.getImageFromDrawingView()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)

    let string = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
    if ( string as NSString).containsString("Simulator")
    {

        let documentsDirectoryURL = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL!

        let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image" + savedImageCounter.description + ".jpg")
        NSLog("Doc URL is " + documentsDirectoryURL.description)
        UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)!.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true)
    }
```

The following line :

```
let string = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
```

used to return "iPad Simulator" and so I would be able to save the photos to a known location on my computer. However, now this call just returns "iPad" or 'iPhone' and the simulator portion isn't there anymore. 
How do I know where the image is saved locally on the computer now that I can't tell where the simulator saves them?

Would love any input.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do things like that at runtime.  There's no reason for you to do at runtime what you can do at build time.  Use TargetConditionals.h and do something like:

```
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
    NSLog(@"This is a simualtor.");
#else
    NSLog(@"This is a device.");
#endif
```

As for determining where your container is on disk, just run:

```
xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.mycompany.myapp
```